# Using values from foreach in QueryOver statement

Tags: c#, .net, closures, queryover

say I want to iterate over a list of IDs and use them to compare some properties in a QueryOver-statement as in:

```
foreach(int id in myIdList)
{
    QueryOver<Tabe> query = QueryOver.Of<Table>()
      .Where(t => t.SomeForeignKey == id);
}
```

Now my compiler advised me to create an extra variable for the iterator id, as it will otherwise be treated as a closure accessing a foreach-variable. So to be on the safe side I adjustet the code to:

```
foreach(int id in myIdList)
{
    int id1 = id;
    QueryOver<Tabe> query = QueryOver.Of<Table>()
      .Where(t => t.SomeForeignKey == id1);
}
```

And the compiler stopped complaining.

For the first version the compiler said, that the behaviour of the statement differs depending on the  compiler version, so I am wondering in which cases it would be save to use the first expression and why it produces correct / incorrect results. And why is it in the end better to use the second version?

Thank you for any insights!

Comment: Accessing a modified closure can cause *unexpected results*. Microsoft fixed this oversight in the C# 5 compiler. This question already has an answer [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13633696/2015959).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read more about [Closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), you can see the more details about usage in C# at "Delegates (C#, D)" section of the link